# Does multi inheritance in Python override the parent inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, parent

I have a question regarding the multi-level inheritance in Python. Following classes are in my script.

```
class A():
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x

class B():
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x

class C(A):
  def __init__(self, x):
    super.__init__(x)
    self.x = x

class D(B,C):
  def __init__(self, x):
    super.__init__(x)
    self.x = x
```

I'm not sure if my question will be understandable but I will try to explain.

- If class C inherits from class A the form in class C will be a rectangle.
- If class C inherits from class B the form in class C will be a circle.
- But if **class D** inherits **class B** (Circle class) first and then **class C(A)** it will be a circle form although **class C** still inherits from **class A** (in the script). The other way around **D(C,B)** it will be a rectangle form (looks like because C(A) will be initialized first)

Why does the multi-inheritance in **class D** "override" the parent from **class C** to be a circle instead of a rectangle form?

Comment: What do you mean "rectangle" and "circle". Can you provide concrete examples to clarify your question?

Comment: Python uses an algorithm called C3 Linearization to compute what's called a Method Resolution Order, which is how it tells in what order it inherits from parent classes.  This article explains that algorithm and walks through some examples: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: It's about the game pong with help of the library pygame. class A and B inherits the Form for the ball from a base class. class A creates a rectangle shape and class B creates a circle shape. class C is the actual game ball and the form is decided by the inheritance of class A or B. If I create a new ball in class D that inherits from class B (circle shape) and class C (predefined with inherited rectangle shape in another file I can't change) I will get a circle shaped ball. I think I'll get this because class D inherits from class B first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance#3277407